# Receiving Json in HttpPost - ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post

I've set up a page to do an HTTP Post with a Json serialized generic list, to a different page in ASP.net.  When it goes to the new page though, I can't seem to find the body of the HTTP Post.

This is the method for the post:

```
    public static void SendHttpPost(string json)
    {            
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:57102/Post.aspx");

        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Although this is the first time I've done this, I presumed you would be able to access the Json using Request.Form or similar, but Request.Form is empty. I've had a good look at the VS degugger and can't see it anywhere in the Request object, but the content length is 68000 bytes, so I'm sure it's in there somewhere!

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?  Many thanks

Comment: If i understand well, what you send to the page "/Post.aspx" should be in Request.InputStream (https://gist.github.com/leggetter/769688). Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for thanks - perfect.  If you add that as an answer, then I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the Request Body using `Request.InputStream` as shown here : gist.github.com/leggetter/769688 !